# How can get weekly data , corresponding to values in sql server ? Please refer below attached image

Tags: sql-server-2012

> I want to get weekly date wise data ,corresponding to values  in **sql server**.
>
> data like date.
>    `date         tariff` .
>     `27/03/2017     1`.
>     `28/03/2017     1`.
>     `29/03/2017     2`.
>     `30/03/2017     2`.
>     `31/03/2017     6`.
>     `1/03/2017      6`.
>     `2/03/2017      6`.
>
> Result like.
>   `FROM DATE    TO DATE   TARIFF`.
>   `27/03/2017   28/03/2017   1`.
>   `29/03/2017   30/03/2017   2`.
>   `31/03/2017    02/04/2017  6`.
>
> Please refer below snapshot.

[image: Example of Question]

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding....!

```
create table #traffic (date date, tariff int)

insert into #traffic values
 ('28 Feb 2017','6')
,('27 Jan 2017','1')
,('28 Jan 2017','1')
,('29 Jan 2017','2')
,('30 Jan 2017','2')
,('01 Jan 2017','6')
,('02 Jan 2017','6')

select * from #traffic

select t1.date 'from', t2.date 'to', t1.tariff from(
(select date,tariff,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by tariff order by date) rn1  from #traffic) t1
join (select date, tariff, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by tariff order by date desc) rn2 from #traffic t) t2 
on t2.rn2 = 1 and t1.rn1 = 1 and t1.tariff = t2.tariff)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the original table is called Table1 you could try

```
SELECT MIN(Date) AS 'FROM DATE', MAX(Date) AS 'TO DATE', Tariff
FROM Table1
GROUP BY tariff
```